# Google App Engine creating background thread exception

Tags: java, multithreading, google-app-engine

I'm trying to run a long-running process in Google App Engine using Java. (basically i need something like a daemon thread? or just something runs indefinitely and doesn't block UI but can still communicate with other threads)

so i tried:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TestingAServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(final HttpServletRequest req, final HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    resp.getWriter().println("hi, from background thread");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();

        System.out.println("done");
    }
}
```

but i get an exception:

java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup")

how do i make a background thread that runs indefinitely on GAE with java?

Comment: What is your use case? If you explain your use case we might be able to come up with a specific solution.

Comment: my use case for now is just having a thread that runs indefinitely and polls for another API every 30 minutes, collect some data, and send emails to alert ppl if necessary. it sounds like Amber gave the right answer with Cron jobs, maybe spinning off tasks for emails, and using memcache to store the collected data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AppEngine doesn't allow usage of traditional threads.

You can, however, use the Modules API to spawn background tasks:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/#Java_Background_threads
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/ThreadManager

Note that such background tasks can only be spawned on manual scaling instances.

Comment: yeah, i was starting to look into that, but does this mean i have to pay for using modules? let's say i just need 1 instance to run 24/7 that periodically polls every 30 minutes. i can't tell if this counts as the "max 5 instance for free apps" restriction??

Comment: Yes, it counts towards that restriction. If all you need to do is poll every 30 minutes, why not just set up a cron to do it instead? If the processing is expected to take more than 60 seconds, you can have the cron add a task to a task queue that is then processed, which can run for up to 10 minutes without needing a dedicated instance.

Comment: Note that you can also make threads on frontend instances, however they can not outlive the request: [ThreadManager.createThreadForCurrentRequest(..)](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/ThreadManager#createThreadForCurrentRequest(java.lang.Runnable)) So you can have parallel threads on frontend instances that run for max of 10 minutes (if executed via Task Queue).

Comment: @Amber you're totally right. i didn't know about cron jobs because i'm a crappy app developer that does't know half the tools in backend. i made the thingy work now with Cron jobs though. this is awesome. thank you so much!!! <3